# android custom spinner. selected item in blue color

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am using a custom spinner. It is almost similar to default, except that I need to set padding at left of each item ( in the drop down padding in each row before text). I am able to do that. But I also want to show the selected item in a different color when list of values are displayed to user as dropdown.

I have used text view as drop down item.

Can someone please suggest if it can be done. I have tired to achieve this with xml, but I couldn't find any option.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT :
Text of selected item in Blue color.

Answer (score 3):

You could specify `android:dropDownSelector="@color/spinner_selector"` for the spinner element and define the spinner_selector color to #800000FF, for example.

See
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html#attr_android:dropDownSelector

Answer (score 1):

You Can Do it by following code.

Just apply style to your textview as background.

// TextStyle is xml file which contain following code.

```
<item android:state_selected="false"
    android:drawable="@android:color/white" />

<item android:state_selected="true"
    android:drawable="android:drawable="@android:color/blue"" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change color of textview at runtime by using spinner's method setOnItemSelectedListener.
For Example,

```
  spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv );
            tv.setTextColor(R.color.green);
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
```